# Non-Blocking Timer C++

Tags: c++, timer, nonblocking

I'm trying to create a simple non-blocking timer in C++ that can be reset. I've google searched for a while to find some code examples but everything I find is either too complicated to understand or does not compile without extra non example code.

I have a program that logs a key press to a file, but I want this file to be written over one seconds after the key has been pressed unless another key has been pressed before the second is up.

I believe I should use Win32 timers, (I am using windows) however I can't find a simple compilable example of their use.

for example this method taken from the info page:

```
SetTimer(hwnd,                // handle to main window 
IDT_TIMER1,                   // timer identifier 
1000,                        // 1-second interval 
(TIMERPROC) MyTimerProc);     // no timer callback 


VOID CALLBACK MyTimerProc( 
HWND hwnd,        // handle to window for timer messages 
UINT message,     // WM_TIMER message 
UINT idTimer,     // timer identifier 
DWORD dwTime)     // current system time 
{

// my proceedure code 

FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
OUTPUT_FILE = fopen("LOG.TXT", "w");
fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "");
fclose(OUTPUT_FILE);

// writes a blank text file.


KillTimer(hwnd, IDT_TIMER1); // stop timer after one call
}
```

doesn't compile because the IDT_TIMER1 hasnt' been defined I think.

Also, I'm not sure if this would be reset by calling it twice or would just start two separate calls 1 second apart.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's trivial, you can just use any number (like 1) instead of `IDT_TIMER1`. All you'd do normally is something like `const int IDT_TIMER1 = 1;` C++11 actually gives you the tools in `<chrono>` to make your own without using Windows-specific functions, though. For the nonblocking part, C++11 also provides `<thread>`.

Comment: The reason you're not finding a simple compilable example is that even a trivial Win32 API C program take a whole mess of boilerplate. But have you tried the code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_timer?

Comment: Yeah that link is pretty much what I'm trying to work through but no single example will compile by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are responsible for giving `ID_TIMER1` a value.  I believe you (99%) also have to have a windows message loop for it to work.

Here are a couple of minimal, compilable [examples](http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/petzold/ch08c.htm).

Comment: Yes, you definitely need a WndProc message loop. But then it's hard to imagine how any kind of timer implementation could work without either spawning a thread (which you'd have to know about an join somehow) or requiring some kind of event loop…

Comment: I could create a new thread and then use sleep(1000), after which I would write the file... the only problem with that is having some way of checking the thread way alive and if it was, killing and restarting it before it completes. But is that a good way of going about things ?

Comment: You can be 100% certain that a message loop is required. There are 3 different ways to use a timer. First, you can pass `NULL` for the window handle to the `SetTimer` function. In that case, you will have to process the `WM_TIMER` in your application's message loop and dispatch it to the appropriate window yourself. Second, you can specify the handle to a particular window when you call `SetTimer`, and in that case, that window's window procedure will receive `WM_TIMER` messages. Third and finally, you can specify a `TimerProc` callback function when you call `SetTimer`, and this function...

Comment: will be called whenever the timer expires. But even in this case, you will need to be running a message loop, because the call to the `TimerProc` function happens inside of the `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` functions.

Comment: any chance of a simple compilable example ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Hardware Performance Timer, which can be quickly found via google, or if you want something more cross platform use the timegettime method, which can also be found via google, neither need a Win32 message loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a window or even an event loop. Look at the [WaitForSingleObject function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is some code

```
HANDLE hStdin; 
hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 

FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
OUTPUT_FILE = fopen("LOG.TXT", "w");

bool previous_input_written = TRUE;

switch (WaitForSingleObject(hStdin, 1000) {

  case WAIT_OBJECT_0:  
    // input happened on hStdin 
    if (!previous_input_written) {
      // the previous input was not saved to file
      fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, ...
      previous_input_written= TRUE;
    }
    ReadConsoleInput(hStdin, ...
    previous_input_written = FALSE;

  case WAIT_TIMEOUT: 
    // the 1000ms delay timed out, write to file
    fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, ...
    previous_input_written= TRUE;
}


fclose(OUTPUT_FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following console program works. It sets a timer using `SetTimer` 
then loops in a message loop. The message loop receives and processes `WM_TIMER` messages 
and the timer callback also is called for each time interval. And it does not block.

```
#define STRICT 1 
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream.h>

VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT nIDEvent, DWORD dwTime) 
{
  cout << "Time: " << dwTime << '\n';
  cout.flush();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) 
{
    int Counter=0;
    MSG Msg;

    UINT TimerId = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 500, &TimerProc); //SetTimer

    cout << "TimerId: " << TimerId << '\n';
   if (!TimerId)
    return 16;

   while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
   {
        ++Counter;
        if (Msg.message == WM_TIMER)
        cout << "Counter: " << Counter << "; timer message\n";
        else
        cout << "Counter: " << Counter << "; message: " << Msg.message << '\n';
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

   KillTimer(NULL, TimerId);
return 0;
}
```